# Charge time capacitor in a BJT collector with a parallel resistor

Tags: capacitor, constant-current, charge, time

[image]

Hello, Given that circuit that has a constant current(let's say 3mA), How do I determine the charge time of that capacitor? since in t=0 the capacitor would have all the current but later it will split, so I can't use the usual formula(Vc=Vi(1-e....), but also can't use I=C*dV/dt since I would vary with time. How can I model the behavior of the charge time through the capacitor?
and how does I do it if instead of a resistor I would have a diode? thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: I would want to do this using a simulator for the diode scenario but, for the simple parallel resistor, the answer I gave to your previous question works just fine.

Comment: Your circuit is not a current source btw, a restive divider putting the base voltage at say 7 to 8 V would be a much better current source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$\small V_C=V_R\$, therefore

\$\frac{1}{C}\large\int \small I_C\: dt=R(0.003-I_C)\$

Solve for \$\small I_C\$; initial condition is: \$\small t=0, I_C=0.003\: A\$.

Assuming a perfect diode that switches on at 0.7 V, the capacitor will charge linearly to 0.7 V, at which point the diode switches on and carries the 3 mA thereafter.

Comment: Thanks, how would you find out the exact time that Ic aproximates to 0?(or that C charges fully) I have given a shot but I'm not sure if I did it right, could you show me?

Comment: In theory, it would never get there. Practically, five time constants is often used.

Comment: or the time it takes to get to X voltage value

Comment: Solving the differential equation gives: \$\small I_C=0.003\:e^{-t/RC}\$. \$\small V_C\$ gets to \$\small 3\:V\$ when \$\small I_R=3\:mA\$ and hence \$\small I_C=0\$. The exponential is normally assumed to be dissipated when \$\small t=5\tau=5RC\$

Comment: ... with 3mA and R=1k the maximum voltage available is 3V and that is at t=infinity. You can find t for any value of Vc less than 3V from the exponential formula. If you want more than 3V, then increase the value of R.

Answer (score 0):

For the RC circuit the charge time is simply 5*R*C, the current does not matter.

```
t = 5 * 1 k * 1 uF
t = 5 ms
```

For the diode circuit, the charge time is how long it takes the cap to charge to 0.7 V given a constant 3 mA current:

```
Q = C * V
t * I = C * V
t = (C * V) / I
t = (1 uF * 0.7 V) / 3 mA
t = 233 us
```